# Open devTools in chrome, and select "Network", click "XHR", and there are extra information in any page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I am used to use chrome to develop websites. Since I update chrome a few days ago,nowadays when I press `F12` to open`devTools` and inspect `XHR` information in Network Tab, there are some extra information in any website I opened.

They seems the same in any page and I don't think they give me any helpful information.Just like this(Because I am a newer in stackoverflow, I don't have enough information to upload a image):

1) **topFrame.js**: pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/content/require

2) **Clipper.js**: pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/content

3) **ContentPreview.js**: pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/content

....

I clicked an item and this is the information

> Request URL:chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/content/require/topFrame.js
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
>
> - Response Headers
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
>
> cache-control:no-cache
>
> Content-Security-Policy:script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com;
>
> object-src 'self';
>
> ETag:"q8EB5SgZxiXLnpp59dDdOwETTQE="
>
> - Request Headers
>
> Provisional headers are shown
>
> Referer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36

From the url, I guess it may be the extension of my chrome? How can I hide these information? I don't think these information helpful. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicated, because it asks about very specific files. I was looking for the same answer, and I figured out that those scripts are being called from Evernote Web Clipper extension. Just disable this extension while you do your tests.

Comment: @DavidRissatoCruz Thank you very much! It really works! I have been confused about this problem for a few months. The solution on that question where Barmar points out, is not really work, because I have to input the filter every time which is not actually!